# ( numberOfRowsInSection ) ' Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm using a UITableView in my project but don't have a `numberOfRowsInSection` in my class but class is giving this error. Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'. Do you want to add protocol stubs? How to solve this problem?

Comment: before implement delegatge assing delegate and data source to your tableview. self.tableview.delegate = self

Answer (score 2):

Under the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, there are certain functions which provide default values.

For example, the method `optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` is optional and it provides the default implementation which returns `1`.

However, this protocol contains two methods which are not optional and they have to be implemented. They are:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

And

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Here are the stabs for those functions to get you started:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

And here is the official documentation of the protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

Comment: The method `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` is outdated. It's highly recommended to use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` which returns a non-optional cell.

Comment: That's a good point @vadian. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add two methods in ViewController. It is required methods Tableview implementation. 
First confim protocal on ViewController

1. numberOfRowsInSection
2. cellForRowAt

// Return the number of rows for the table.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 0
}
```

// Provide a cell object for each row.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)

   // Configure the cell’s contents.
   cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell text"

   return cell

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just select the red circle in the "Do you want to add protocol stubs?" and it will automatically add all the methods from UITableViewDataSource into your class. Then you just have to implement them like this example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 2 //the number of rows you want in your table view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath) //this gives you a cell, dequeue means that it will not create cells for every row you need, but it will reuse them as an memory optimisation
   cell.textLabel!.text = "Text" //sets the text in the cell for the corresponding index path

   return cell
}
```

The same will be needed for UITableViewDelegate if you want to know when the user interacts with the tableView. Good luck! :)